# javascript/google map api if statement inside for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

im doing a multiple marker in google map api with designated icon image depends on the value i created an IF statement for icon but its not showing im having an error on my console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
   on this line

```
 if (cicon[i][0]<= 1.49) {
```

this is my whole script

```
      <script>


     var cicon = <?php echo json_encode($js_array1); ?>;//added
     var locations = <?php echo json_encode($js_array); ?>;
     console.log(cicon);//added
     console.log(locations);//added
     var image1 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_1.png";
     var image2 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_2.png";
     var image3 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_3.png";
     var image4 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_4.png";
     var image5 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_5.png";
     var image6 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_6.png";
     var image7 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_7.png";
     var image8 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_8.png";
     var image9 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_9.png";
     var image10 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_10.png";
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.599512, 120.984222),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
       if (cicon[i][0]<= 1.49) {
          icon: image1,
          } elseif (cicon[i][0]<=2.49){ icon : image2

        }elseif (cicon[i][0]<=3.49){ icon : image2

          }elseif (cicon[i][0]<=4.49){ icon : image2

       }elseif (cicon[i][0]<=5.49){ icon : image2

          }elseif (cicon[i][0]<=6.49){ icon : image2

            }

     map: map
       });
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
       })(marker, i));
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: what do i need to do sir, where do i need to place the if/elseif block?

Comment: @nnnnnn No. And at least explain how/why you say that.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - ah, I didn't see the closing `)`. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `if` statement in implicit object definitions and you cannot use `elseif` (use `else if` instead). To get rid of the first error, use function instead.

```
var cicon = <?php echo json_encode($js_array1); ?>;//added
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($js_array); ?>;
console.log(cicon);//added
console.log(locations);//added
var image1 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_1.png";
var image2 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_2.png";
var image3 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_3.png";
var image4 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_4.png";
var image5 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_5.png";
var image6 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_6.png";
var image7 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_7.png";
var image8 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_8.png";
var image9 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_9.png";
var image10 = "/IntensityMeter/icon_img/number_10.png";
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 5,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.599512, 120.984222),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),

// Notice function here
 cicon: (function(){

    if (cicon[i][0]<= 1.49) {
    return image1;
    } else if (cicon[i][0]<=2.49){ return image2

  }else if (cicon[i][0]<=3.49){ return image2

    }else if (cicon[i][0]<=4.49){ return image2

 }else if (cicon[i][0]<=5.49){ return image2

    }else if (cicon[i][0]<=6.49){ return image2

      }

  })(),

map: map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {
  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
 })(marker, i));
}
```

What caused your error is using `if` statement to define object key. For example, if you want to create new object depending of value of variable `a`, this will return an error:

```
someObject = {
    someParam: someValue,
    someOtherParam: someOtherValue,
    if(a < 5){
        param3: 'a lower than five'
    }else{
        param3: 'a biger or equal to five'
    }
};
```

You can use `if` statement only in scope of some function. Correct way will be:

```
someObject = {
    someParam: someValue,
    someOtherParam: someOtherValue,
    param3: (function(){if(a < 5){
            return 'a lower than five'
        }else{
            return 'a biger or equal to five'
        }
    })()
};
```

Comment: while i still receiving some error this time on line having
elseif (cicon[i][0]<=2.49){return image2;} and the red underline is on 
{return image2;}

Comment: @michaeljohnperalta. Sorry, my typo. You need to add `,` after function. Corrected.

Comment: @michaeljohnperalta. Try it now.

Comment: @michaeljohnperalta. Oh, I see now. Why you think `elseif` exists in javascript? Use `else if` instead.

Comment: What is the `cicon` property of the `Marker` class?